# Partitioning of MySQL tables doesn't seem to increase performance

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, partitioning

I have a huge table with a company IDX (unique ID for each of my companies) as a Partition Key.

I have around 10,000 companies and each company might have up to 200,000 rows.
I have increased the number of partitions, but my query performance doesn't seem to have increased.

**Shall I increase the number of partitions??** Up to one partition per company (for the companies having a lot of rows)?

What is the best architecture solution for me?
I've heard about indexing but not sure if it's relevant in my case.

Comment: Partitions are not a magic "make things faster" feature. In some ways they are not really much more than a clustered index (where the clusters are stored in separate files), and can actually **hurt** performance on queries that the partitioning criteria are not relevant to. Partitioning isn't usually the first thing you should be looking at to improve performance, indexing is.

Comment: maybe I can do indexing on my partitioned tables?

Comment: If each company can only access it's own rows, and very little querying is done across companies, a partition can make sense (but so can separate databases entirely in that scenario); but even then partitions are not a substitute for appropriate indexes. For example, regardless of partitioning, if you have a lot of date based queries, the fields used for the date conditions should be indexed.

Comment: I have also timestamps for each company, and most of the time, I request a specific time frame. What should I do in that case?

Comment: If you have a lot of queries on something like company_id and some_timestamp, the best index is typically `(company_id, some_timestamp)`.... not two separate indexes on each field.

Comment: Thank you. When I create this index, does that apply to the full table or I need to specify this index for every single partition at a time?

Comment: I've never had a use case for using partitions myself so I can't say with 100% sureness, but the lack of any partition options on the CREATE INDEX syntax suggests indexes apply across partitions. It's my understanding that partitions are primarily more of a storage option, and only a sorting one as more of a side effect.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (with or without partitioning) so we get a feel for the data.  And provide the most important queries, so we can help you with indexing and/or partitioning.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics.  PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is going to be useful for improving performance and concurrency if all `SELECT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements include the partition column (partitioning expression) in the `WHERE` clause (or equivalent predicate in the `ON` clause of a join). Otherwise, if our queries are looking at all partitions, then we aren't going to see a performance improvement.

To gain a performance benefit, we need optimizer to make effective use of *partition pruning* in the execution plan; to eliminate from consideration all of the partitions where it is known that matching rows will not be found.

Before launching into creating more partitions, we need to ensure that queries (at least the ones we want performance from) are getting execution plans that are getting partition pruning.

We should first check at the execution plans, to see what affect partitioning has. We use `EXPLAIN` for that. (Newer versions of MySQL, partitioning info is shown by default. For older releases of MySQL, we used `EXPLAIN PARTITION` to get that info.)

Not stated in the question is which type of partitioning is in use (RANGE, LIST, HASH, COLUMNS, KEY), what the partition expression is, or what the WHERE clauses look like. So we can't venture a guess as to whether we'd expect partition pruning.

---

**INDEXES**

For large sets, indexes are *always* relevant.

Which indexes we need to create and maintain, which indexes are most appropriate,  really depends on the actual mix of queries that are being executed.

Partitioning is *not* a substitute for suitable indexes.

Comment: I have also timestamps for each company, and most of the time, I request a specific time frame. What should I do in that case?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan, and verify that there is partition pruning going on. From the description in the question, it seems like we may be expecting a query to access a single partition. We should verify that's whats happening.  For accessing a specific time frame, I'd make sure that we've got sargable predicates (comparisons on bare columns, not columns wrapped in functions or other expressions) and have a suitable index defined; likely we want a composite index.  With only general problem statement, we can only give general guidelines, we can't give specific recommendations.

Comment: I can't emphasize this enough.:  **use `EXPLAIN`** to see the execution plan.   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html